# Percentages using SQL Common Table Expression or any other approach please?

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]

For Getting Dataset2 I am using the Following CTE

```
;WITH RecordsWithNoDuplicates_CTE (RowNo,[Name]
       ,[DateAdded]
      ,Reason
   ) AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name Order by DateAdded DESC) AS 'RowNo'
    ,Name,
    DateAdded,
    Reason
 FROM 
    MyTable
)
SELECT * FROM RecordsWithNoDuplicates_CTE where rowno=1
```

For getting Dataset3 I am doing the following

```
  ;WITH RecordsWithSpecificCase_CTE (RowNo,[Name]
           ,[DateAdded]
          ,Reason
       ) AS
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name Order by DateAdded DESC) AS 'RowNo'
        ,Name,
        DateAdded,
        Reason
     FROM 
        MyTable
    WHERE REASON='Case1'
    )
    SELECT * FROM RecordsWithSpecificCase_CTE where rowno=1
```

I need to calculate the Percentage of records specific to a Reason=Case1 out of All Records in Datset2

Comment: Start with the queries for Datasets 2 and 3 and add COUNTs to them.  Then combine the new queries using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that you get an output row for each row in the "2" query regardless of any matches in the "3" query.  Then a quick `COALESCE` to fill in zeroes in the "3" count as needed, multiple by 100 and divide by "2" count.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the comment above a little...

In your situation I would probably first make a view or function to get the latest records. This
is simply a wrapper around your CTE, and will stop you having to duplicate it.

```
CREATE VIEW LatestRecords
AS
    WITH RecordsWithNoDuplicates_CTE  AS
    (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name Order by DateAdded DESC) AS RowNo,
        Name,
        DateAdded,
        Reason 
    FROM 
        MyTable
    )
    SELECT * FROM RecordsWithNoDuplicates_CTE WHERE RowNo=1
```

This view then is available for subsequent queries and functions, such as this one:

```
SELECT 
    100*Count(CASE WHEN Reason='Case1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)/Count(*) as Percentage
FROM LatestRecords
```

which will count the number of occurences of a latest record with reason="Case1", and divide it by the total number of latest records (giving your percentage).